# Detect a form class in the inheritence tree

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a winforms application, in which I need sometimes to indirectly inherits From the class `Form`

**Example**

```
public class FormTest : TemplateForm 
{
}

public class TemplateForm : Form
{
}
```

The problem is that the design of `FormTest` is disabled because it didn't inherit directly from `Form` class.

[image: capture]

When iclick into `Show Call Stack` I had

```
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

So, How can I change this behaviour and make the design enable , I mean how can I make the design of the form enable when the `Form` class is detected in its inheritence tree?

Comment: What do you mean by `the design of FormTest is disabled`? provide a screenshot if possible..

Comment: That should be fixed if you rebuild the solution, worst case restart the visual studio.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I don't think that , sorry :(

Comment: If base class is in different assembly, then rebuild that assembly alone separately. close the form, then open it again from solution explorer and see if that helps?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I tried it but i get the same error

Comment: Too bad, Click on `Show call stack` and post it please, there might me some unhandled exception going in constructor or form load (in designer alone), it happens sometimes when you access shared members which are not initialized when using designer.

Comment: @LamloumiAfif, show `TemplateForm` code, do you override any 'Paint' method that might cause the error?

Comment: My final guess, try not execute any code in constructor of base form as well as form load. You can add condition             `if(!this.DesignMode){ //Your code here }`. May be that can help.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thank you , but I haven't constructor in the base class , it is by default

Comment: @LamloumiAfif Check whether you have subscribed `form_Load` or `form_Shown` or overridden `OnLoad`, `OnShown` methods, apply `if(!this.DesignMode){ //Your code here }` there if any.

Comment: I'd like to hear does that solved your problem? or at least helped?

Comment: No, unfortunately It didn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you're asking for is [Visual inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z3efhd2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), make sure you have given at least `protected` access for the controls you need to access in the derived class. Then you'll be able to access them in designer.

Note:Nevertheless some controls like `DataGridView`, `TableLayoutPanel` etc prevents them from being edited through derived class via designer. Am not sure why.